# Static file error on Django windows server

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I installed my project on Windows server, but it cannot see the static files.

I tried many examples on the internet, but I could not solve the problem. please guide me on this

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static/")


#STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},     name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) 
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`python manage.py collectstatic` This is the result I get when I do it:

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

C:\inetpub\vhosts\demo.com.tr\httpdocs\static
This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type ‘yes’ to continue, or ‘no’ to cancel: yes

0 static files copied to ‘C:\inetpub\vhosts\demo.com.tr\httpdocs\static’, 126 unmodified.
```

Comment: Show Django error log lines related to static files requests, clarify is DEBUG=true or false,  describe whether you are trying to run Django app behind Nginx/Apache/IIS or you call `runserver`, show example of the problematic static file URL, specific error message from browser devtools, show how you define links to static files in your project templates.